# equivalent setting in Jest to files options in Karma

Tags: angular, karma-runner, jestjs

I am wondering what is an equivalent setting in Jest to files options in Karma.

Currently I am trying to set up Jest test for my Angular projects. I have a library which sould be loaded before the test starts. In case of karma, it works fine by setting the path to the library as files option. I do not know where to set it in Jest.

I have a  reference error like A is not defined.
I tried specify the file in transformignorepatterns, but it does not work. Then, wrote global.A = require(path to the lib). It caused an error like cannot read B of undefined (=A is still undefined).

I found similar question [Include static library file in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48060416/include-static-library-file-in-jest) but there are no questions. So I asked by my self.

Comment: actually trick with global [should work](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/708). maybe you should try having that in config file?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually, I did it in setupJest file. I will try again.